# Batch file to check if file created in current month is present or not

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a batch file to check if a file present in a particular folder with last modified date as current month & year is present or not.

Ex: for this month to display `FEB-16 (02/2016);` (date doesn't matter to me)

The folder/filename i can input as it is static.

Comment: I have improved the readability a little bit. However, have you tried something so far? It is easier to get an answer if you show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set /p "file=Enter your file here: "
if not exist "%file%" (
    echo file %file% not found
    goto end
    )
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
    for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=-: " %%g in ("%%~ti") do (
        if "%%h%%g"=="%YYYY%%MM%" (
            echo %%i is from this month!
            )
        if not "%%h%%g"=="%YYYY%%MM%" (
            echo %%i is not from this month!
            )
        )
    )
:end
pause
```

**EDIT**

Locale unspecific version:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set /p "file=Enter your file here: "
if not exist "%file%" (
    echo file %file% not found
    goto end
    )
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
    set "escapedFile=%%~dpnxi"
    set "escapedFile=!escapedFile:\=\\!"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic datafile where name^="!escapedFile!" get LastModified /value') do set "dt2=%%a"
    set "YYYY2=!dt2:~0,4!" & set "MM2=!dt2:~4,2!"
    if "!YYYY2!-!MM2!"=="!YYYY!-!MM!" (
        echo %%i is from this month!
        )
        if not "!YYYY2!-!MM2!"=="!YYYY!-!MM!" (
        echo %%i is not from this month!
        )
    )
:end
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to add a message for the below cases:

Comment: 1. If no file is present in that path

Comment: 2. If file is present but it doesn't satisfy the date criteria

Comment: I tried running this but it says "Syntax of this command is incorrect"

Comment: What did you enter as filename? Did that file exist? Try entering `*` as filename and see if it gives an error

Comment: Yes, the files was present. When it prompted me to enter the file name I gave something like this: D:\New.txt

Comment: Can you execute this command in your cmd and tell me what it prints? `FOR %i IN ("D:\new.txt") DO echo %~ti`

Comment: it gives out: Today's date with time

Comment: Tried this new one you have given. Looks good for files with name as a single word. But if file name has space or numbers then it throws an error. Any way to handle this?

Comment: @GaneshP If my answer solved your problem, you should consider clicking the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it. See [this](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for why this is important.

Comment: Thank you. Tried this one out but whatever file I choose of this month, it just says it is not of this month.

Comment: I was trying this in a different system where the command: FOR %i IN ("D:\new.txt") DO echo %~ti --> 02/11/2016 06:31 PM gives this output

Comment: @GaneshP I'll try to create a local unspecific version

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the meantime, is there a minor tweak that can done to make this work for date in the format: 02/11/2016?

Comment: @GaneshP "tokens=1,3 delims=/: "